# Scraping in python to using open api

Tags: python, web-scraping, openapi

i want to scraping "www.naver.com"
so i tried to scraping using open api
i wrote code following this:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
defaultURL = 'http://openapi.naver.com/search?&'
key = 'key=keyvalue'
target='&target=news'
sort='&sort=sim'
start='&start=1'
display='&display=100'
query='&query='+urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(input("write:")))

fullURL=defaultURL+key+target+sort+start+display+query

print(fullURL)
file=open("C:\\Users\\kimty\\Desktop\\k\\python\\N\\naver_news.txt","w",encoding='utf-8')

f=urllib.request.urlopen(fullURL)
resultXML=f.read()
xmlsoup=BeautifulSoup(resultXML,'html.parser')

items=xmlsoup.find._all('item')

for item in items:
    file.write('---------------------------------------\n')
    file.write('title :'+item.tile.get_text(strip=True)+'\n')
    file.write('contents : '+item.description.get_text(strip=True)+'\n')
    file.write('\n')

file.close()
```

but python shell only show this

> ```
> ============= RESTART: C:\Users\kimty\Desktop\kpython\N\N.py =============
> write:lee
> http://openapi.naver.com/search?&key=keyvalue&target=news&sort=sim&start=1&display=100&query=lee
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\kimty\Desktop\k\python\N\N.py", line 19, in <module>
>     f=urllib.request.urlopen(fullURL)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
>     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 464, in open
>     response = self._open(req, data)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 482, in _open
>     '_open', req)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
>     result = func(*args)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1211, in http_open
>     return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1186, in do_open
>     r = h.getresponse()
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1227, in getresponse
>     response.begin()
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 386, in begin
>     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 356, in _read_status
>     raise BadStatusLine(line)
> http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
> ```

why this happening?
what about that python shell talk to me?
i am using windows 8.1 64x, python 3.4.4

Answer (score 0):

This http.client.BadStatusLine is a subclass of http.client.HTTPException. It gave you a http error back, maybe your API key is wrong! If I try to access the link with my browser it also gives me an error.

[This](http://openapi.naver.com/search?&key=Qu7WDklZz81qOexEvIJg4O1zsFw0eb&target=news&sort=sim&start=1&display=100&query=lee) is the exact address you tried to request.

Edit

Some people have fixed this error by importing the http lib.

Comment: i tried line by line, it work. i think run all  command at the same time, cause error. i don't know why. but it work to run line by line.